# Subroutines with same name

Tags: types, fortran

I am trying to have same name for two subroutines but am getting the error:

```
gfortran gshapes.f08 gshapes_utest.f08 -o gshapes_utest.x
gshapes_utest.f08:53.41:

call ellips%set_ellipse_corner (crnr1, crnr2)
                                     1
Error: Type mismatch in argument 'xlen' at (1); passed TYPE(gcorner) to REAL(4)
```

This is the type definition and associated subroutines:

```
type, public :: Ellipse
type(GCenter) :: centr  ! Center coordinate of ellipse
type(GCorner) :: crnr1  ! Upper left corner
type(GCorner) :: crnr2  ! Botton right corner
real :: xlen
real :: ylen            ! Size of ellipse in x- and y-directions
character (len=12) :: parm  ! Parameterisation of ellipse
contains
  procedure :: set_cpnt_ellipse
  procedure :: set_ellipse_corner => set_spnt_ellipse, set_tpnt_ellipse
  procedure :: print => print_ellipse
end type Ellipse

contains

! \brief Initialize geographical coordinate system grid object

subroutine set_cpnt_ellipse (ellips, gcentr, xlen, ylen)
  class(Ellipse) :: ellips
  type(GCenter) :: gcentr
  real :: xlen, ylen

  ellips%centr = gcentr
  ellips%xlen = xlen
  ellips%ylen = ylen
  ellips%parm = 'center'

end subroutine set_cpnt_ellipse


subroutine set_spnt_ellipse (ellips, gcrnr, xlen, ylen)
  class(Ellipse) :: ellips
  type(GCorner) :: gcrnr
  real :: xlen
  real :: ylen

  ellips%crnr1 = gcrnr
  ellips%xlen = xlen
  ellips%ylen = ylen
  ellips%parm = 'corner'

end subroutine set_spnt_ellipse


subroutine set_tpnt_ellipse (ellips, gcrnr1, gcrnr2)
  class(Ellipse) :: ellips
  type(GCorner) :: gcrnr1
  type(GCorner) :: gcrnr2

  ellips%crnr1 = gcrnr1
  ellips%crnr2 = gcrnr2
  ellips%parm = 'corners'

end subroutine set_tpnt_ellipse
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put them in an interface block:

```
interface set_tpnt_ellipse
  module procedure set_spnt_ellipse, set_cpnt_ellipse
end interface
```

Comment: I call them a different name, set_spnt_ellipse and t_tpnt_ellipse.         Then I use procedure :: set_ellipse_corner => set_spnt_ellipse, set_tpnt_ellipse in the defined type, which does not seem to work. It is always picking the first subroutine declared.

Comment: The problem is that the subroutines are contained in a type declaration.

Comment: Fortran complains with Error: 'set_ellipse' at (1) is not a member of the 'ellipse' structure

Comment: I have added it inside the type declaration and Fortran is giving me Error: MODULE PROCEDURE at (1) must be in a generic module interface

Comment: In the derived-type definition, I specify a type-bound-procedure-part, which consists of a CONTAINS statement, followed by some procedures.

Comment: This seems to work      generic :: set_ellipse => set_spnt_ellipse, set_tpnt_ellipse

Comment: This place only lets me add comments. Code looks a mess. I can try open another question with the answer

Comment: Check: Resolving type-bound procedures depending on the data type of the argument

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246687/resolving-type-bound-procedures-depending-on-the-data-type-of-the-argument